# Average 2 consecutive rows in Panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataset which looks as follows

```
userid time           val1 val2 val3 val4
1      2010-6-1 0:15  12   16   17   11
1      2010-6-1 0:30  11.5 14   15.2 10
1      2010-6-1 0:45  12   14   15   10
1      2010-6-1 1:00  8    11   13   0
.................................
.................................
2      2010-6-1 0:15  14   16   17   11
2      2010-6-1 0:30  11   14   15.2 10
2      2010-6-1 0:45  11   14   15   10
2      2010-6-1 1:00  9    11   13   0
.................................
.................................
3 ...................................
.................................
.................................
```

I want to get the average of every two rows. Expected results would be

```
userid time           val1  val2  val3  val4
1      2010-6-1 0:30  11.75 15    16.1  10.5
1      2010-6-1 1:00  10    12.5  14    5
..............................
..............................
2      2010-6-1 0:30  12.5  15    16.1  10.5
2      2010-6-1 1:00  10    12.5  14    5
.................................
.................................
3 ...................................
.................................
.................................
```

At the moment my approach is

```
data = pd.read_csv("sample_dataset.csv")
i = 0
while i < len(data) - 1:
    x = data.iloc[i:i+2].mean()
    x['time'] = data.iloc[i+1]['time']
    data.iloc[i] = x
    i+=2
for i in range(len(data)):
    if i % 2 != 1:
        del data.iloc[i]
```

But this is very inefficient. Therefore can someone point out me a better approach to get the intended result?. In the dataset, I've more than 1000000 rows

Comment: Do you want to reduce the data frame too?

Comment: @KenrySanchez Yes, So ideally size should reduce by half :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution stays in pandas, and is far more performant than the `groupby-agg` solution:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(10),
                   "b":range(0, 20, 2),
                   "c":pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=10, freq='H')})
>>> df

   a   b                   c
0  0   0 2018-01-01 00:00:00
1  1   2 2018-01-01 01:00:00
2  2   4 2018-01-01 02:00:00
3  3   6 2018-01-01 03:00:00
4  4   8 2018-01-01 04:00:00
5  5  10 2018-01-01 05:00:00
6  6  12 2018-01-01 06:00:00
7  7  14 2018-01-01 07:00:00
8  8  16 2018-01-01 08:00:00
9  9  18 2018-01-01 09:00:00

>>> pd.concat([(df.iloc[::2, :2] + df.iloc[1::2, :2].values) / 2,
            df.iloc[::2, 2]], axis=1)

     a     b                   c
0  0.5   1.0 2018-01-01 00:00:00
2  2.5   5.0 2018-01-01 02:00:00
4  4.5   9.0 2018-01-01 04:00:00
6  6.5  13.0 2018-01-01 06:00:00
8  8.5  17.0 2018-01-01 08:00:00
```

Performance:

```
In [41]: n = 100000

In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(n), "b":range(0, n*2, 2), "c":pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods= n, freq='S')})

In [44]: df.shape
Out[44]: (100000, 3)

In [45]: %timeit pd.concat([(df.iloc[::2, :2] + df.iloc[1::2, :2].values) / 2, df.iloc[::2, 2]], axis=1)
2.21 ms ± 49.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).agg(lambda x : x.iloc[-1] if x.dtype=='datetime64[ns]' else x.mean())
7.9 s ± 218 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using `resample`

```
df.set_index('time').resample('30Min',closed = 'right',label ='right').mean()
Out[293]: 
                      val1  val2  val3  val4
time                                        
2010-06-01 00:30:00  11.75  15.0  16.1  10.5
2010-06-01 01:00:00  10.00  12.5  14.0   5.0
```

Method 2

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).agg(lambda x : x.iloc[-1] if x.dtype=='datetime64[ns]' else x.mean())
Out[308]: 
                 time   val1  val2  val3  val4
0 2010-06-01 00:30:00  11.75  15.0  16.1  10.5
1 2010-06-01 01:00:00  10.00  12.5  14.0   5.0
```

Update solution

```
df.groupby([df.userid,np.arange(len(df))//2]).agg(lambda x : x.iloc[-1] if x.dtype=='datetime64[ns]' else x.mean()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is another column. I've updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne about your update dataframe , you can try method 2

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne check the update solution

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne notice I convert the Time to datetime `df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
`

Comment: Wow, making this code really proves that you're a pandas guru

Comment: @Wen-Ben I tried the updated solution. Seems it works :) But my userid filed get disappeared and some unnamed field comes (I guess auto increment field)

Comment: @Wen-Ben Lol :-)

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne did you try reset_index？

Answer (score 0):

I tried both mentioned answers. Both did work. But Noah's answer was the fastest one as I experienced. Therefore I marked that answer as the solution.
Here is my version of Noah's answer with some explanation and edits to map with  my dataset

In order to use Noah;s answer time column should be first or last (I maybe wrong). Therefore, I moved the time column to end

```
col = data.columns.tolist()
tmp = col[10]
col[10] = col[1]
col[1] = tmp
data2 = data[col]
```

Then I did the concatenation. Here **::2** means every second column and **:10** means columns from 0 to 9. And then I add the time column which is at the 10th index

```
x = pd.concat([(data2.iloc[::2, :10] + data2.iloc[1::2, :10].values) / 2, data2.iloc[::2, 10]], axis=1)
```